# Regex - grouping the titles into a standardized form

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am completely new to regex and would appreciate if someone could help me out here. :)

I have an input text that consists of headings followed by few lines. I wish to group the headings and corresponding content that comes under each heading in 2 separate arrays (or as 2 columns in a dataframe).

Example:

the input text :

**Inclusion Criteria** for all fruit lovers:

extract this line 2

extract this line 3 as well

**Exclusion Criteria** for all fruit lovers:

extract this exclusion line 2

extract this exclusion line 3 as well

**Inclusion Criteria** for apple lovers:

extract this line

extract this line as well

**Exclusion Criteria** for apple lovers:

extract this line

extract this line as well

the **inclusion criteria** for both apple and orange lovers

extract this exclusion line 2

extract this exclusion line 3 as well

the **exclusion criteria** for both apple and orange lovers

extract this exclusion line 2

extract this exclusion line 3 as well

**desired output :** all the content that comes under inclusion criteria keyword in the title should be grouped together under Inclusion Criteria, similarly all the content that comes user keyword exclusion criteria in title should come under Exclusion Criteria

[Inclusion Criteria :
extract this line 2 extract this line 3 as well
...
...
..
]

[Exclusion Criteria:
extract this exclusion line 2
extract this exclusion line 3 as well
.....
....
..]

Regex I tried forming:  `Inclusion Criteria\s*(.*?)\s*Exclusion Criteria|Inclusion Criteria\s*(.*)(\n\n).*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a pattern, you can use 3 capture groups, and in capture group 1 and 2 match either `In` or `Ex` *clusion* to deternmine the difference.

In capture group 3, you can match all lines that belong to that block.

```
^.*\b(?:([Ii]n)|([Ee]x))clusion [Cc]riteria\b.*((?:\n(?!.*\b(?:[Ii]n|[Ee]x)clusion [Cc]riteria\b).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\b` Match the whole line and then a word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `([Ii]n)|([Ee]x)` Capture `In` in **group 2**, or Ex in **group 3**
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `clusion [Cc]riteria\b` Match *clusion* and the word Criteria
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `\n` Match a newline
    - `(?!.*\b(?:[Ii]n|[Ee]x)clusion [Cc]riteria\b)` Assert that the line does not contain the exclusion criteria part
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close and optionally repeat the non capture group
- `)` Close group 3

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpNtdp/1) with the capture group values.

---

Capturing the lines in 2 different lists for example:

```
import re
import pprint
pattern = r"^.*\b(?:([Ii]n)|([Ee]x))clusion [Cc]riteria\b.*((?:\n(?!.*\b(?:[Ii]n|[Ee]x)clusion [Cc]riteria\b).*)*)"

s = ("Inclusion Criteria for all fruit lovers:\n\n"
            "extract this inclusion line\n\n"
            "extract this inclusion line as well\n\n"
            "Exclusion Criteria for all fruit lovers:\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 2\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 3 as well\n\n"
            "the inclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 2\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 3 as well\n\n"
            "the exclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 2\n\n"
            "extract this exclusion line 3 as well")
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)

inclusion_criteria = []
exclusion_criteria = []

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if match.group(1):
        inclusion_criteria.append(match.group(3))
    if match.group(2):
        exclusion_criteria.append(match.group(3))

print("Inclusion Criteria")
pprint.pprint([s.strip() for s in inclusion_criteria if s])
print("Exclusion Criteria")
pprint.pprint([s.strip() for s in exclusion_criteria if s])
```

Output

```
Inclusion Criteria
['extract this inclusion line\n\nextract this inclusion line as well',
 'extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well']
Exclusion Criteria
['extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well',
 'extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well']
```

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird this helped alot, thanks. Would it also be possible to consider - incase  the content below the  title contains "exclusion criteria" or "inclusion criteria", in any of the lines , but it should not be considered as separate inclusion or exclusion title.

input:
**Inclusion Criteria** for all fruit lovers:\n\n"
            "extract this inclusion line\n\n"
            "extract this **inclusion criteria**  line as well\n\n"
output:
[**Inclusion Criteria**
            "extract this inclusion line\n\n"
            "extract this **inclusion criteria**  line as well\n\n]

Comment: @Angie You can, but then you would have to check for the line starting with `Inclusion Criteria` See https://regex101.com/r/UQOAy9/1

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird , Okay, so now when I try the initial data in the updated regex pattern.. it returns me 2 empty arrays.. so it means the updated regex works only when inclusion/exclusion criteria comes in the beginning?... So to consider both scenarios, would it be a good idea to put a condition to check both cases/patterns, and return the desired output/values when either pattern is found? could you please help me with code? Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Angie I am not sure that I exactly know what you mean. Can you create/update a regex101 example like https://regex101.com/r/UQOAy9/1 with your content, and then point out what you want to match, and what should not match? You need some logic to separate what is the title with Inclusion and what is not.

Comment: @ The fourth bird , The solution you suggested for my first scenario, perfectly solved my requirement with the regex `^.*\b(?:([Ii]n)|([Ee]x))clusion [Cc]riteria\b.*((?:\n(?!.*\b(?:[Ii]n|[Ee]x)clusion [Cc]riteria\b).*)*)`

Now, the second scenario I'm trying to solve is a combination of the first scenario, and the one that is explained in the body of this regex demo. 
(https://regex101.com/r/uOImcL/1)

Therefore, now I am trying to handle both scenarios in one regex. Is that possible?

Comment: O/P: 
Inclusion Criteria
['extract this line 2\n\nextract this line 3 as well, but in case the term inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria appears anywhere in this sentence or any sentences/lines under the titles , i do not want it to be considered as a title, as it is a content that comes under inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria  titles',
 'extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well']
Exclusion Criteria
['extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well',
 'extract this exclusion line 2\n\nextract this exclusion line 3 as well']

Comment: @Angie So these matches are not the expected? https://regex101.com/r/NqpIi3/1 These matches are from the start of the string for Inclusion and Exclusion Criteria.

Comment: Not exactly, because we have 2 more titles there in the example - `the inclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers` and `the exclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers`. The title may or may not start with inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria. And it gets even tricky if all the letters in the title comes in capitals (in some cases)

Comment: this is how it goes, and trying to do it in one regex : (1). all the content that comes under inclusion criteria keyword in the title should be grouped together under Inclusion Criteria, ( key takeaway is that a `\n\n` occurs after every title, before the content starts. (2)similarly all the content that comes under keyword exclusion criteria in title should come under Exclusion Criteria. (3) The titles may or may not be  in capitals

Comment: (4) in case the term inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria appears anywhere in the body of the sentence/lines under the titles , it should not  be considered as a title, as it is a content that comes under inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria  titles.

I hope you got what I am trying to solve. @The fourth bird

Comment: @Angie But even for the first line `Inclusion Criteria for all fruit lovers:` that follows with `\n\n` and the third line `extract this line 3 as well, but in case the term inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria appears anywhere in this sentence or any sentences/lines under the titles , i do not want it to be considered as a title, as it is a content that comes under inclusion criteria or exclusion criteria  titles.` that also follows with `\n\n` there is no way to tell which one is a title or not. See https://regex101.com/r/zvRcoH/1

Comment: Yes, @The fourth bird, you are absolutely right. Therefore I have updated the body and have put in a more realistic data mixed with my sample data(most data is likely to follow this structure) - see ( regex101.com/r/Czw9Z1/1 ) This is taken from a public site ( clinicaltrials.gov ) I believe here, you will get a better picture. As you can see, after each title its a `\n\n` and soon after the body ends(lines under the title) its a `\n`, and then the new title begins. Would it be possible to write a regex covering the 4 points I mentioned above.. if we consider this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

**Not the best solution but will do for your case(not regex)**

```
data = '''Inclusion Criteria for all fruit lovers:
extract this line 2
extract this line 3 as well
Exclusion Criteria for all fruit lovers:
extract this exclusion line 2
extract this exclusion line 3 as well
Inclusion Criteria for apple lovers:
extract this line
extract this line as well
Exclusion Criteria for apple lovers:
extract this line
extract this line as well
the inclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers
extract this exclusion line 2
extract this exclusion line 3 as well
the exclusion criteria for both apple and orange lovers
extract this exclusion line 2
extract this exclusion line 3 as well'''
newline_split = data.split('\n')
space_removal = [i for i in newline_split if i.strip()]
keywords = ['Inclusion Criteria', 'Exclusion Criteria', 'inclusion criteria',
        'exclusion criteria']
get_index_inclusion_exclusion = [space_removal.index(i) for i in space_removal
                             if any((j in i) for j in keywords)]
start_index = get_index_inclusion_exclusion[0::2]  # inclusion index
stop_index = get_index_inclusion_exclusion[1::2]  # exclusion index
inclusion_line = []
exclusion_line = []
if len(start_index) > len(stop_index):
   maxi_len = len(start_index)
if len(start_index) < len(stop_index):
   maxi_len = len(stop_index)
else:
   maxi_len = len(start_index)
for i in range(maxi_len):
   if len(start_index) > len(stop_index):
       try:
          inclusion_text = space_removal[start_index[i] + 1:stop_index[i]]
       except IndexError:
           inclusion_text = space_removal[start_index[i] + 1:]
       for j in inclusion_text:
           inclusion_line.append(j)
       try:
           exclusion_text = space_removal[stop_index[i] + 1:start_index[i + 1]]
           for k in exclusion_text:
               exclusion_line.append(k)
       except IndexError:
           pass
   if len(start_index) < len(stop_index): # stop index should not be greater than start index...if exceeds,it extracts till the start index only
       try:
           inclusion_text = space_removal[start_index[i] + 1:stop_index[i]]
           for j in inclusion_text:
               inclusion_line.append(j)
       except IndexError:
           pass
       try:
           exclusion_text = space_removal[stop_index[i] + 1:start_index[i + 1]]
           for k in exclusion_text:
               exclusion_line.append(k)
       except IndexError:
           pass
   if len(start_index) == len(stop_index):
       inclusion_text = space_removal[start_index[i] + 1:stop_index[i]]
       for j in inclusion_text:
           inclusion_line.append(j)
       try:
           exclusion_text = space_removal[stop_index[i] + 1:start_index[i + 1]]
       except IndexError:
           exclusion_text = space_removal[stop_index[i] + 1:]
       for k in exclusion_text:
           exclusion_line.append(k)


print(f'Inclusion Criteria :{inclusion_line}')
print(f'Exclusion Criteria :{exclusion_line}')
```

Comment: the above code works only if inclusion comes first followed by exclusion. if order changes u have to the change the code little bit

Comment: Hey, yes this did solve my requirement. Thank you so much. Just one doubt, when I increase the length of the data, it says list index out of range?.. do you have suggestion for that. It would be of great help!.

Comment: @Angie yep if inclusion and exclusion headers wasn't in same length it causes Index error.i have updated the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).